# C# com obfuscated not working in c++ project

Tags: c#, c++

I use C# language and develop a com dll, and use C++ calling managed code via COM, succeed.
Then I obfuscate the C# com dll by [obfuscar](http://code.google.com/p/obfuscar/) excluding interfaces and com exported class.
And I use C++ calling the COM dll, failed when create com object.
Why? Is there any other class or interface should be exclude?
Thank you.

Comment: I wouldn't have thought so. What errors exactly? Has the typelib version changed? Are you e.g. using reflection for a dispatch interface?

Comment: Failed when calling CoCreateInstance function, typeLib not found.

Comment: OK - does that mean obfuscar stripped or obfuscated the resources? Can you manually extract the typelib from the original one and add it back in afterwards, or get obfuscar to leave it as-was?

Comment: The resources is obfuscated. Thank you, Let me try to set obfuscar to exclude the resource. How to add the typelib back in afterwards?

Comment: I don't know, sorry, haven't done it in years. One of the Microsoft tools can probably do it, or one of the hits for 'Windows resource editor' on Google should work.

Comment: Thank you very much. Let me try tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First unregistered your old .NET assembly (not obfuscated one) with the command:

```
regasm /u yourassembly
```

Then register it again with /tlb option to generate the tlb file again and then compile the C++ project with new tlb file. The command is:

```
regasm /tlb yourassemly
```

Note, the regasm.exe is under C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework{.NET version Number}, different version of .NET has different regasm.exe, also it has both 32 bit and 64 bitversion, you must use the right one.

Comment: I will also try your method, thanks. By the way, I should note that CoCreateInstance function' return result is E_NOINTERFACE.